# Serverless Nodejs Application gives Error "Unsupported Framework" when invoking

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to deploy an existing node js application using serverless on AWS infrastructure.

my yaml is like :

```
service: todo-app-api
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x

functions:
     app:
        handler: server.run
        events:
          - http:
              path: /
              method: ANY
              cors: false 
          - http:
              path: /{proxy+}
              method: ANY
              cors: false
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

SLS deploy works fine and it creates lambda and other resources well. But when invoking that getting internal server error, when I see aws logs it gives error details as

```
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Unsupported framework",
    "stack": [
        "Error: Unsupported framework",
        "    at getFramework (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-http/lib/framework/get-framework.js:69:9)",
        "    at module.exports (/var/task/node_modules/serverless-http/serverless-http.js:14:21)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/server.js:31:22)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)",
        "    at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:75:12)",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:95:12)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)"
    ]
}
```

can somebody tell me if anything wrong I have done?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do you have a `server.js` file inside the same directory as your `serverless.yaml`, and does it include a line like `module.exports.run = (event, context, callback) => {` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was actually problem at my end. 
code in my server.js file was like

`module.exports.run = sls(app_1);`
instead of

`module.exports.run = sls(app_1.default);`

Also in my app.js file 
`exports.default = new App().app;`

My code is working fine now.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for documenting `app_1.default`, this is not available in other examples and this proved to be the factor that fixed this error for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and even [opened an issue](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/issues/164) in the official repo. Everything was because I had in my `serverless.yml`:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-http # <---- delete this line
  - serverless-offline
```

I don't really know how it got there but deleting it solved my problem. I hope it helps and good luck :-)